# Question about creating a CNN in a certain way (without model.add)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a question about the following CNN. I am used to keras code, and normally when I see models they are built along these lines:

```
def foo_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(30, (5,5), kernel_initializer='normal', padding='valid', input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(15, (3,3), kernel_initializer='normal', padding='valid', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

So, basically, **initialize** the type of model, then keep adding layers (layer-by layer), **compile** the model and then return it. I am doing a sentiment analysis, and I stumbled upon the following CNN:

```
def ConvNet(embeddings, max_sequence_length, num_words, embedding_dim, labels_index):

    embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            embedding_dim,
                            weights=[embeddings],
                            input_length=max_sequence_length,
                            trainable=False)

    sequence_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

    convs = []
    filter_sizes = [2,3,4,5,6]

    for filter_size in filter_sizes:
        l_conv = Conv1D(filters=200, kernel_size=filter_size, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
        l_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(l_conv)
        convs.append(l_pool)


    l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)

    x = Dropout(0.1)(l_merge)  
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    preds = Dense(labels_index, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

I am having trouble understanding how the layers are built up in this CNN. When I initialize the model with my data the model summary looks as follows;

[image: Model Summary]

I'm having trouble to **understand the structure** of this model, so how it was built. For instance, what does the sequence_input and variable do? Why is there a for-loop that seems to create the Conv1D layers and the GlobalMaxPooling1D layers, but they don't seem to be added anywhere? Why is there a variable x being re-declared three times (for the dropout, dense, and dropout layers), and where do all the layers get added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question one by one:

> *what does the sequence_input and variable do?*

Whenever we define a model (deep neural network model specifically) we have to declare the input dimensions. Since in this case, the input is an array/list of length 50. If input is an image data, the input could have been something like (250,250,3) or (length,width,number_of_channels) for the image.

> *why is there a for-loop that seems to create the Conv1D layers and the
>   GlobalMaxPooling1D layers, but they don't seem to be added anywhere?*

In this example, the way I understand is, the model is created with multiple filter/kernel sizes, which is defined in a list. So, for each size, the CNN layers are applied along with the pooling layers, and later everything is appended as a list, which is finally merged or stacked together to form the CNN layers

[Refer section:

```
l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)

    x = Dropout(0.1)(l_merge)
```

]

> *Why is there a variable x being re-declared three times (for the dropout, dense, and dropout layers),*

it is not being declared 3 times, but a sequential model is created and each of the layers defined are being added in a stack. [Consider a pointer concept if it helps to explain:
in step one, let's say a = b+c, then let's say a points to m (a->m), where m = m * m, so essentially you do is (b + c) * (b + c) till this step.]

> *where do all the layers get added*

In the following steps:

```
 l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)

    x = Dropout(0.1)(l_merge)  
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    preds = Dense(labels_index, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Just to explain, when you do x = {*some_operation*}(x) , it means that the previous layer operation of x, is being passed as an input to the current layer of operation which you again pass as an input to the next layer. So essentially we create a chain of layers.

I hope it answers your queries. If not feel free to ask more, will try to help :)

Comment: Thanks! Clear answer! Can you elaborate a bit more on the conv-global max pooling setup? In the model summary, why are the convolutional layers presented before the max-pooling layers? Normally you first have a conv layer, than a max pooling layer, then a conv layer again right?

Comment: Yes, ideally pooling is used to down-sample the output from the conv layers. Here, keeping so many pooling layers is actually not helping much. Better way to keep it like conv -> pooling -> conv-> pooling and so on